# Mapping methods across multiple columns in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe where the values are lists:

```
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.DataFrame({'X':[[1, 5], [1, 2]], 'Y':[[1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 5]]})
DF
         X          Y
0   [1, 5]  [1, 2, 5]
1   [1, 2]  [1, 3, 5]
```

I want to check if the lists in X are subsets of the lists in Y. With individual lists, we can do this using `set(x).issubset(set(y))`. But how would we do this across Pandas data columns?

So far, the only thing I've come up with is to use the individual lists as a workaround, then convert the result back to Pandas. Seems a bit complicated for this task:

```
foo = [set(DF['X'][i]).issubset(set(DF['Y'][i])) for i in range(len(DF['X']))]

foo = pd.DataFrame(foo)
foo.columns = ['x_sub_y']
pd.merge(DF, foo, how = 'inner', left_index = True, right_index = True)

         X          Y   x_sub_y
0   [1, 5]  [1, 2, 5]   True
1   [1, 2]  [1, 3, 5]   False
```

Is there a easier way to achieve this? Possibly using `.map` or `.apply`?

Comment: OP, if you are using Scott Boston's answer, I recommend using `np.vectorise` as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163829/4909087

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `set` and `issubset`:

```
DF.assign(x_sub_y = DF.apply(lambda x: set(x.X).issubset(set(x.Y)), axis=1))
```

Output:

```
        X          Y  x_sub_y
0  [1, 5]  [1, 2, 5]     True
1  [1, 2]  [1, 3, 5]    False
```

Comment: If I vectorise your answer, I get a [4x speedup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163829/4909087) on this tiny dataset.

Comment: Btw, you don't need t convert `x.Y` to a set.

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**
`set` conversion and `difference` using `np.where`

```
df_temp = DF.applymap(set)
DF['x_sub_y'] = np.where(df_temp.X - df_temp.Y, False, True)
DF
        X          Y  x_sub_y
0  [1, 5]  [1, 2, 5]     True
1  [1, 2]  [1, 3, 5]    False
```

---

**Option 2**
Faster, `astype` conversion

```
DF['x_sub_y'] = ~(DF.X.apply(set) - DF.Y.apply(set)).astype(bool)
DF 
        X          Y  x_sub_y
0  [1, 5]  [1, 2, 5]     True
1  [1, 2]  [1, 3, 5]    False
```

---

**Option 3**
Fun with `np.vectorize`

```
def foo(x):
     return not x

v = np.vectorize(foo)    
DF['x_sub_y'] = v(DF.X.apply(set) - DF.Y.apply(set)) 
DF
        X          Y  x_sub_y
0  [1, 5]  [1, 2, 5]     True
1  [1, 2]  [1, 3, 5]    False
```

Extending [Scott Boston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163839/4909087) for speed using the same approach:

```
def foo(x, y):
    return set(x).issubset(y)

v = np.vectorize(foo)

DF['x_sub_y'] = v(DF.X, DF.Y)
DF
        X          Y  x_sub_y
0  [1, 5]  [1, 2, 5]     True
1  [1, 2]  [1, 3, 5]    False
```

### Small

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 460 µs per loop           # Before       
10000 loops, best of 3: 103 µs per loop          # After
```

### Large (*`df * 10000`*)

```
1 loop, best of 3: 1.26 s per loop               # Before   
100 loops, best of 3: 13.3 ms per loop           # After
```

Comment: does it make sense to "timeit" against a two-rows DF?

Comment: @MaxU If the difference is so vast for a couple of rows, then there may be no need to time for a larger one... but I can do it :)

Comment: a timing for a larger data set might (not necessarily) show quite different results...

Comment: @MaxU Thanks for asking... appreciating `np.vectorise` even more now :-) (why haven't I used it before? x))

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try `set`

```
DF['x_sub_y']=DF.X+DF.Y
DF['x_sub_y']=DF['x_sub_y'].apply(lambda x : list(set(x)))==DF.Y
DF
Out[691]: 
        X          Y  x_sub_y
0  [1, 5]  [1, 2, 5]     True
1  [1, 2]  [1, 3, 5]    False
```