# Parsing a column of JSON strings

Tags: python, json, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a tab seperated flatfile, one column of which is JSON data stored as a string, e.g.

```
Col1        Col2                    Col3
1491109818  2017-08-02 00:00:09.250 {"type":"Tipper"}
1491110071  2017-08-02 00:00:19.283 {"type":"HGV"}
1491110798  2017-08-02 00:00:39.283 {"type":"Tipper"}
1491110798  2017-08-02 00:00:39.283 \N
...
```

What I want to do is load the table as a pandas dataframe, and for col3 change the data to a string with just the information from the type key. Where there is no JSON or a JSON without a type key I want to return None.

e.g.

```
Col1        Col2                    Col3
1491109818  2017-08-02 00:00:09.250 Tipper
1491110071  2017-08-02 00:00:19.283 HGV
1491110798  2017-08-02 00:00:39.283 Tipper
1491110798  2017-08-02 00:00:39.283 None
...
```

The only way I can think to do this is with iterrows, however this is very slow when dealing with large files.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        df.loc[index, 'Col3'] = json.loads(row['Col3'])['type']
    except:
        df.loc[index, 'Col3'] = None
```

Any suggestions on a quicker approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *`np.vectorize`* and *`json.loads`*

```
import json

def foo(x):
    try:
        return json.loads(x)['type']
    except (ValueError, KeyError):
        return None

v = np.vectorize(foo)
df.Col3 = v(df.Col3)
```

Note that it is never recommended to use a bare `except`, as you can inadvertently catch and drop errors you didn't mean to.

---

```
df

         Col1                     Col2    Col3
0  1491109818  2017-08-02 00:00:09.250  Tipper
1  1491110071  2017-08-02 00:00:19.283     HGV
2  1491110798  2017-08-02 00:00:39.283  Tipper
3  1491110798  2017-08-02 00:00:39.283    None
```

Comment: Doesn't `vectorize` just hide the for loop?

Comment: @James It hides, and it speeds it up. You need to see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163829/4909087 Also, the try-except approach is fast -- (faster than if conditions, EAFP and so on), so I'd recommend sticking with it.

Comment: Interesting, does the speed up come from broadcasting to the underlying numpy array?

Comment: @James I'm not sure broadcasting is applicable here, but I definitely know there's some amount of parallelisation going on.