# How to print index (Row number) while conversion error during json.loads Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am using below code for Json load which works fine for valid json string, but for non valid it throws error.

```
orgdf['data'].apply(json.loads)
```

[image]

I just need to know for which index (row number) there is an invalid record for which Jason.loads giving error.

I know I can do it using dataframe enumeration (for loop), but looking for an efficient way to do that as it contains Million records.

It will be great if someone can help on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom function where you wrap the `json.loads` call in a try/except and then call this function inside `apply`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20725965/5726768).

```
def is_valid_json(s):
    try:
        json.loads(s)
    except (json.JSONDecodeError, ValueError):
        return False
    return True

# Mark valid JSON strings
valid = orgdf['data'].apply(is_valid_json)

# Extract indices with _invalid_ strings
invalid_indices = valid[~valid].index
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine :) However not sure if its ending up with same space time compexity or not.

Comment: You're right, the complexity will be probably similar. `json.loads` isn't easy to vectorize, you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46175465).